# Best way to submit UL form with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have a difficult form to submit. There are multiple

attributes in the ul. And in the Li attributes there are multiple div's like this:

```
<form id="formtosubmit" class="form-style-12" action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <ul name="products">
        <!-- products added to the cart will be inserted here using JavaScript -->
        <li class="product" name="product">'
            <div class="product-image">
                <a href="image">
                    <img src="images/" alt="placeholder"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="product-details">
                <a style="color: black;">product</a>
                <span class="price"></span><br>
                <div class="quantity">
                    <label>Aantal: ' + qty + '</label>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <a href="#0" class="delete-item">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I know I need to put input attributes/tags in the li attributes because you can't submit li attributes. But how do I need to do this with all those div's? just at the start of the li?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a hidden input item:
`<input type="hidden" value="foo" name="bar" />`

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input-field

```
<form id="formtosubmit" class="form-style-12" action="checkout.php" method="post">
<ul name="products">
    <li class="product" name="product">
        <input type="hidden" name="somename" value="somevalue />
        ...
    </li>
</ul>
```